# ERROR:root:Cell magic `%%R` not found

Tags: r, jupyter, rpy2

I have python 3 env

installed rpy2 with

```
conda install -c r rpy2=2.8.5
```

load the cell magic in jupyter notebook with

```
%load_ext rmagic
```

when I try to use R block in notebook, it gives me the error

```
ERROR:root:Cell magic `%%R` not found.
```

Answer (score 15):

In a terminal:

```
pip install rpy2
```

In a notebook:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

Then you can use `%%R`:

```
%%R
var <- c(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: This one should be the best anwser for this question!

Answer (score 1):

This is a link to the best answer I have found to the problem given on this thread: 
[R Notebook](https://answers.dataiku.com/14/in-an-r-notebook-i-have-the-error-cell-magic-r-not-found).

This link states that the error means that R is not configured in your DSS instance.
You need to install R manually.

The commands given on the forum post are:

> 1. Install the R packages **RJSONIO** and **HTTR** in any R console.
> 2. Install the Python package **rpy2:**
>
>    `pip install rpy2`

Afterward, they give the following link:
[configure R](http://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/installation/r.html).

I hope this is helpful and well worded.